# Unittesting with an OIDC Auth Server not possible?

Tags: unit-testing, openid-connect, quarkus

tried to write Unit tests for my application but stumbled across following problem.

Since defining an Auth Server (Keycloak in this case) my Quarkus app would not even start without the Auth server running. That's why I want to ask if I can decouple this hard dependency?

I tried to unit test methods that are not secured by any mechanism so the method would be totally independent of a Jwt or an Auth server.

Thanks in advance and kind regards,

Rosario

Application.properties

```
#OIDC
quarkus.oidc.client-id=xxx
#quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=1bef[..]
quarkus.oidc.application-type=service
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/randomRealm
```

Test:

```java
@Test
public void testHelloEndpoint() {
given()
.when().get("/video/hello")
.then()
.statusCode(200)
.body(is("hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can deactivate oidc in the test profile. Simply add the following to your application.properties:

```
%test.quarkus.oidc.enabled=false
```

Note: If you ever want to write tests including a connection to oidc this solution will not work because you cannot mark tests where it should be activated or not. Then you have to start an oidc server like keycloak i.e. with testcontainers. I think Rest-Assured has a method to add credentials for that.

Comment: googled around but not found anything: is there a way to disable datasource as well?

Comment: you cannot deactivate the datasource completely in tests with @QuarkusTest annotation but you can change your datasource to H2, so quarkus automatically starts a H2 in-memory-database for your tests. Add following to your application.properties `%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2`
`%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test`. You also need to add the h2-jdbc-driver to your dependencies like your postgres driver. Have a look at: https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#jdbc-datasource-2

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of quarkus you could mock the auth server https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect#integration-testing-wiremock

In your `pom.xml` add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-test-oidc-server</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the `application.properties` add:

```
# keycloak.url is set by OidcWiremockTestResource
%test.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${keycloak.url}/realms/quarkus/
%test.smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=privateKey.jwk
```

And in your test class use:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(OidcWiremockTestResource.class)
public class YourTestClass {
```